# Applescript get name exception

Tags: applescript, getnameinfo

In one of my scripts I need the file name:

```
set input to choose file multiple selections allowed yes
tell application "System Events"
    set {nameInfo, sourcePath} to {name of item 1 of input, POSIX path of container of item 1 of input}
end tell
```

But if there is a "/" in the file name e.g. "soso/lala.txt" the name comes back as "soso: lala.txt".
I also tried:

```
do shell script "basename " & item 1 of input
```

but then only "lala.txt" arrives. Can I trick it somehow to get "soso/lala.txt" in return?

Comment: I'm getting soso:lala.txt returned on High Sierra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Colons and slashes in file names are error-prone in AppleScript because colons are path separators in HFS paths (the default AppleScript type) and slashes are path separators in POSIX paths

Two suggestions:

1. Use `displayed name`

   ```
   set input to choose file with multiple selections allowed
   tell application "System Events"
       set {nameInfo, sourcePath} to {displayed name of item 1 of input, POSIX path of container of item 1 of input}
   end tell
   ```
2. Use the `Finder`

   ```
   set input to choose file with multiple selections allowed
   tell application "Finder"
       set {nameInfo, sourcePath} to {name of item 1 of input, POSIX path of (container of item 1 of input as text)}
   end tell
   ```